# Oracle SQL Developer treats my comment as a command

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I've created some very basic SQL script:

```
/*
  Change date format
*/
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY';

/*
  Drop old tables (if exists)
*/
DROP TABLE Students;

/*
  Create new tables
*/
CREATE TABLE Students
  (
    Id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName VARCHAR2(20),
    FirstName VARCHAR2(10),
    Address VARCHAR2(10),
    BirthDay DATE,
    GroupId NUMBER(3)
  );

/*
  Check the table was created successfully
*/
DESC Students;

/*
  Insert a new record to the table
*/
INSERT INTO Students VALUES(101, 'Solin', 'Dan', 'Beer-Sheva', '01/02/1985', 11);

/*
  Check the record was inserted succesfully
*/
SELECT * FROM Students;

/*
  Add 'AvgMark' field to the table with default of 0
*/
ALTER TABLE Students ADD AvgMark NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT 0;

/*
  Check that the new field was added
*/
DESC Students; 

/*
  Insert 3 new records to the table
*/
INSERT INTO Students VALUES(102, 'Tal', 'Ruti', 'Tel-Aviv', '10/07/1988', 12, 70);
INSERT INTO Students VALUES(103, 'Kohen', 'Yossi', 'Dimona', '01/08/1987', 11, 80);
INSERT INTO Students VALUES(104, 'Toys', 'Vered', 'Tel-Aviv', '15/09/1988', 12, 90);

/*
  Check the records were inserted succesfully
*/
SELECT * FROM Students;

/*
  Change 'Address' data type to VARCHAR2(15)
*/
ALTER TABLE Students MODIFY Address VARCHAR2(15);

/*
  Check that the data type has changed
*/
DESC Students; -- Some comment
```

At the end of the `Script Output` i get this Error Message:
`ERROR: object COMMENT does not exist`

If i'll change the comment to `Hello World` i'll get the same error for `WORLD` "object"...

I changed the whole script to avoid single line comments, and the result is the same.

I could avoid it again in this example but i really want to understand what's causing this weird problem...

---

Another thing which might help solving the issue, is another weird error i have in the same script, few lines above the comment. in this line: 
`ALTER TABLE Students MODIFY Address VARCHAR2(15);`

SQL Developer shows me an error under the last two characters (the right parenthesis and the semicolon) saying `Syntax error. Partially recognized rules (Railroad diagrams): ...`

If i'll run the statement it'll work just fine...

Comment: Use `--`.  Two hyphens should always work in SQL code (it's the ANSI standard for comments).

Comment: I guess that's because `DESC` isn't a real SQL statement. It doesn't even require a `;` at the end. `desc students; -- bla` results in "invalid identifier" in SQL\*Plus. And SQL Developer tries to mimic the SQL\*Plus behaviour I guess. So your only option is to not use a `--` comment in the line where you use `DESC`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - actually it's not because `DESC` is a SQL\*Plus command (as opposed to SQL or PL); rather, comments can't come after a statement terminator regardless of what kind of statement that is.

Comment: @mathguy - that's true in SQL\*Plus, but not in SQL Developer, which allows comments after the terminator (in 4.2 at least). But then the OP's example gets the same response with and without the semi-colon ("Usage: DESCRIBE [schema.]object[@db_link]", rather than the error the OP shows - I guess an earlier version?), whereas in SQL\*Plus it gets that without the semicolon and SP2-0565 with it. The mimicking is not perfect *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - is that so for scripts run directly from SQL Developer, or also for scripts run from a file? I assume for scripts run from a file SQL Developer just invokes SQL\*Plus (but I don't have the motivation to test...) {:-)

Comment: If you're going to use SQL\*Plus scripts I strongly suggest you *only* run them in SQL\*Plus.  The only real advantage SQL\*Plus has over any other SQL client is compatibility.  But if you try to emulate it through another tool that compatibility is lost.

Comment: @mathguy - SQL Developer is a completely independent client, it doesn't invoke SQL\*Plus, or need ti to be installed. It's just been designed to work similarly (and has its own SQLcl command line version now too). The behaviour is the same if you run a script, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a SQL Developer bug/feature.

---

desc[ribe] is one of the SQL*Plus statements that are supported by the SQL Worksheet.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/intro.htm#RPTUG10710

---

In SQL Developer we can notice some interesting phenomenons that do not exist in SQL*Plus:
1.
 when given multiple tokens, all token are being ignored except for the last one.

```
desc some gibberish - yada yada yada t3
```

---

```
Name Null Type       
---- ---- ---------- 
C3        NUMBER(38)
```

2.  `--` is not being treated as a notation for line comment, but as an object name.

```
desc --
```

---

```
ERROR:                          
------------------------------- 
ERROR: object -- does not exist
```

3.
A single semicolon is being ignored and not being treated as a statement terminator.

```
desc ; ; ; ; ; ; t1;
```

---

```
Name Null Type       
---- ---- ---------- 
C1        NUMBER(38)
```

Therefore, when given the command -

```
DESC Students; -- Some comment
```

Only the last token 'comment' is being handled and yields an error, since there is no object 'comment'.

Comment: I don't see that behaviour in 4.2; which version are you seeing it in, out of interest?

Comment: @AlexPoole, 4.1.3.20

Answer (score 2):

`--` and `\* *\` and `REM` are all OK in SQL*Plus scripts, but there are several restrictions. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch6.htm#1006369

You ran into the issue discussed in the second paragraph - do not add comments after statement terminators.